# How to intent activity after the animation made with MotionLayout is finished?

Tags: java, android-animation, onclicklistener, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

I used MotionLayout in a project .

The problem was that when the button was clicked, only the animation could be played and the transfer to the next activity was not performed.
The OnClickListener method apparently stops!.

Does anyone have a logical solution to this problem?

**MotionScene**

```
 <Transition
        android:id="@+id/state3"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/next"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/nextLevel"
        app:duration="1000">
        <OnClick
            app:clickAction="transitionToEnd"
            app:targetId="@+id/btnNext" />
    </Transition>
```

**JAVA**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnNext:

             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class));

             break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MotionLayout already provides the listener for getting the Animation progress updates. It's called the TransitionListener. It's a Listener for monitoring events about TransitionLayout.

Here is the code:

```
MotionLayout motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionLayout);

motionLayout.addTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1, float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, boolean b, float v) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the onClick you can do the transition.
motionLayout.transitionToEnd()

If you want to transtionToEnd and then launch the intent. (in 2.1)

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnNext:
             motionLayout.transitionToEnd(() ->
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , LoginActivity.class));
        }
     }
}
```